# Supervaluational semantic equivalence

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm working on Ted Siders Logic for Philosophers and I'm stuck on exercise 3.15.

I need to show the global and local definitions of supervaluational semantic consequence are equivalent. How do I go about getting started on this?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

*Local implies global*.

According to the "local" definition of *semantic consequence* [**Exercise 3.14**, page 103] :

> $\phi$ is a supervaluational *semantic consequence* of $\Gamma$ iff for every trivalent
>   interpretation $\mathscr I$, and every precisification $\mathscr C$ of $\mathscr I$, if $VC_{\mathscr C} (\gamma) = 1$, for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$, then $VC_{\mathscr C} (\phi) = 1$.

We can "semi-formalize" the above definition as follows :

> $\forall \mathscr I \, \, \forall \mathscr C \, , \, $ **if** $VC_{\mathscr C} (\gamma) = 1 \, , \, $ for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$, **then** $VC_{\mathscr C} (\phi) = 1$.

Using the following property of quantifiers :

> $\forall x(\alpha \to \beta) \to (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta)$

we can derive from the above definition :

> $\forall \mathscr I \, , \, $ **if** $\forall \mathscr C \, \, VC_{\mathscr C} (\gamma) = 1 \, , \, $ for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$, **then** $\forall \mathscr C \, \, VC_{\mathscr C} (\phi) = 1$.

But, applying the definition of page 101 :

> if $VC_{\mathscr C} (\phi) = 1$ for every precisification $\mathscr C$ of $\mathscr I$, we say that $\phi$ is *supertrue* in $\mathscr I$

we can rewrite the above condition as :

> $\forall \mathscr I \, , \, $ **if** $\gamma$ is *supertrue* in $\mathscr I$, for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$, **then** $\phi$ is *supertrue* in $\mathscr I$

and this one is the "global" definition of supervaluational semantic consequence : $\Gamma \vDash_S \phi$ of page 101.